# opencv detect cubes (corners)

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing

Problem that I am trying to solve is to detect cubes and get colours from them. I use live images from camera captured by Android phone. Recognition has to be fast (<1s) Example of a cube:

[image]

I also have differently coloured cubes. They can be placed randomly (for example when they touch each other).
I can easily detect one cube, in same cases even two cubes, but the problem is when I have 3 or more and for 2 cubes when they are really close to each other.

Currently processing looks like this:

- blur image with Gaussian
- convert to hsv and use only s channel
- detect edges with Canny
- dilate and erode edges
- use HoughLinesP to get lines
- from lines (I reject too long and too short lines) calculate intersection points and from that get corners of cubes
- knowing corners (must be precise) get colours

[image]
 
nothing detected
[image] 
2 cubes detected (red and orange points are corners and cyan points are intersection points, black lines are detected lines by hough lines)
[image]
nothing detected, some lines found

Basically what I need is to find correct corners of the cubes. I tried using Imgproc.goodFeaturesToTrack and Imgproc.cornerHarris, but it finds too many of them and usually not the most important ones.

I also tried using findContours with no success even for two objects. findContours was also crashing my app after minute of running. At some point I tried using Feature Matching + Homography to find matches to a grayscale image of a cube with the one from camera, but results were messy. Also Template Matching didn't give me good results.

Do you have any idea how to make detection more reliable and precise?

Thanks for help

Comment: try bilateral filtering instead of blurring.

Comment: Can you provide a few non-processed images?

Comment: With a proper pre-processing, you could search for closed contours and make things a lot simpler. I know you tried and something did not work. Imho, it is better to spend time to find out what went wrong.